# Calculating Texture Co-ordinates for a 2D shape from vertices ? iOS OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, textures, glkit

I have a number of 2D polygons which I am drawing using OpenGL ES 2.0 with GLKit. Using these vertices, I have used Quartz2d to draw a UIImage which matches each shape to use as a texture.

What I now want to do is calculate the correct texture UV coordinates for each shape. Is there any easy way to do this ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand correctly, but if you have 2D shape with image mapped onto it as texture then texture coordinates lie in range from 0 to 1 for corresponding vertex coordinates from 0 to image size.

So, `tex.x = vertex.x / imageSize.width`, `tex.y = vertex.y / imageSize.height`.

PS: may be `tex.y = 1.0f - vertex.y / imageSize.height` if image is rendered flipped vertically.